# programming Firefox with MozRepl in Windows 7

Tags: firefox, windows-7, firefox-addon

I've only seen examples for it in Linux. Does it work in Windows? Can you give an example?

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I found this, which might help: "If you’re using Microsoft’s telnet for Windows, it’s probably set to handle one-character-at-a-time instead of one-line-at-a-time. See the Troubleshooting  page, or just use netcat  (recommended) or putty." from http://wiki.github.com/bard/mozrepl/starting-the-repl

Answer (score 3):

MozRepl works just fine on Windows.

Since it runs as a Firefox plug-in and interacts with Firefox internals, the examples you've seen for Linux should work the same on the Windows version.

The only difference is that you might have to download a third-party Telnet client. I prefer [PuTTy](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) personally. Just make sure you select the Telnet protocol and then specify port 4242 (unless you changed it).

I just gave it a shot and everything was fine. I ran through the Tutorial on the site (the same one they walk through in the demo video) and Firefox on Windows behaved just like Firefox on Linux.